# Am adding nodes in racher kubernetes environment using docker command available for adding custom server

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So, the issue is `var/lib/docker` folder is growing rapidly (23G currently, after executing `sudo du -h -d 2 /var/lib/docker`) than expected is there a way to resolve this by some changes in configuration or is it normal that it will take a lot of space.

Comment: What does your question have to do with adding nodes in Rancher or Kubernetes? Can you give an output of `sudo du -h -d 2 /var/lib/docker`?

Comment: 23G var/lib/docker